# Get distance and draw line between two location android google maps

Tags: java, android, geolocation, google-geolocation

I have a app that opens the map and zooms on my location with a marker
and then if i **longClick** on any place it saves that location in database
everything works fine but one thing i cannot manage is draw a line of path between two location markers.

**these are three global variables**

```
 Location myLocation;
 LatLng onmaplongclicklastlatlng;
 private GoogleMap mMap;
```

`mylocation` is assigned by `LocationListener` and `onmaplongclicklastlatlng` is assigned when i long click on any place on the map.

placing the marker on both location is done i already have the two points i want to draw the line on.

i just need to draw a line between those two locations *(my current location periodically updated in the **myLocation** variable)*

and **onmaplongclicklastlatlng** changed whenever i long click on the map.

the whole code is done and i have a `button` that i want to use to `draw` the line 
since i can access the two location `variables` from this `button` method, Other code need not be changed.

```
public void getLine(View view) {

    // need to draw a line here from user gps posiution to the marker location    
}
```

i have tried many tutorials but they do not work for some reason, any help would be really appreciated.

oh and last but not least

```
onmaplongclicklastlatlng
```

is a LatLng and

```
myLocation
```

is a Location

but they can be interchanged to fit the purpose

```
ex. Location maplocation = new Location(onmaplongclicklastlatlng
.latitude, onmaplongclicklastlatlng.longitude);
```

and

```
Latlng myLatLng = new LatLng(myLocation.getLatitude(), myLocation.getLongitude());
```

***As i said any help would be really appreciated.
And let me know if anything else needed i will edit the question then.***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To calculate accurate distance  between two loaction you have to use [Google Map Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro). Construct your url like below.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?" +"origin=" + origin.latitude + "," + origin.longitude+ "&" +"destination=" + dest.latitude + "," + dest.longitude +"&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=driving" + "&" + key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

And to draw line between two location you have to first use the [Google Map Direction Api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start), construct your url like below

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?" +"origin=" + origin.latitude + "," + origin.longitude+ "&" +"destination=" + dest.latitude + "," + dest.longitude +"&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=driving" + "&" + key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

above api call return a list of latlng add the list into polylines

```
 Polyline polyline1 = googleMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                .clickable(true)
                .addAll(latlngList));
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

To add a polyline -

```
 val polyline1 = map?.addPolyline(
            PolylineOptions().clickable(true)
                .add(LatLng(23.8103, 90.4125), LatLng(4.0383, 21.7587))
                .geodesic(true) // this will turn this line to curve
        )
        // To add styles in the line
        stylePolyline(polyline1)

 private fun stylePolyline(polyline: Polyline?) {
        polyline?.let {
            it.color = ContextCompat.getColor(binding.mapPlaceholder.context, R.color.lineColor)
            it.pattern = mutableListOf(Dot(), Gap(5F))
            it.startCap = RoundCap()
            it.jointType = JointType.ROUND
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about these:

https://github.com/zhenyanghua/MeasureTool-GoogleMaps-V3
http://zhenyanghua.github.io/google-maps/measure-tool/

Regards

PS: I am not the author of the software.

Comment: And if you dont want to use this third party api you can check out how its done by them.